# Windows Azure Mobile Service query table

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I use Windows Azure Mobile Service.
I have a table of Element. 
I want to query the cloud database :

- select Id, Name
  FROM Element ORDER BY creationTime

But I don't understand at all the "query" system with Windows Azure Mobile Service.
I have a IMobileServiceTable but don't know what to do with that...

I checked on tutorial, and they explain how to use Where clause, but not select. And I need to select only some column because my element have picture and I don't want to download it in my getAll method....

Edit :

I try that :

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    var query = table.Select(x =>
                new Element()
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Name = x.Name,
                    Price = x.Price
                });
    var _items = query.ToListAsync().Result;
}).ContinueWith((x) => handleProductsArrived(x.Result));
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using .net or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a helpful post from Carlos that includes what the corresponding SQL query would be here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/09/21/playing-with-the-query-object-in-read-operations-on-azure-mobile-services.aspx

For example:

```
function read(query, user, request) {
query.where({ UserId: user.userId })
     .select('id', 'MovieName', 'MovieRating')
     .orderBy('MovieName')
     .take(10);
request.execute();
}
```

woudld translate to

SELECT TOP 10 [id], [MovieName], [MovieRating] 
FROM MovieRating 
WHERE Rating > 2 AND UserId = ? 
ORDER BY MovieName

So for your case where you need to translate

SELECT Id, Name 
FROM Element 
ORDER BY creationTime

you'd go with something like the following:

```
function read(query, user, request) {
    query.where({ UserId: user.userId })
        .select('id', 'Name', 'Element')
        .orderBy('creationTime')
    request.execute();
}
```

Comment: This is on WAMS (windows azure mobile service). How to do it directly on C# ?

Comment: Try using the mssql object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554212.aspx

Comment: The objective is not to use a direct connection to sql => put security credentials inside is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are just looking to do a simple query with `IMobileServiceTable`

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Element ORDER BY creationTime
```

If you do not mind using the `IMobileServiceTable<TodoItem>`, you can try:

1) Removing the member properties you do not need from your Object

Example:

```
public class TodoItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // REMOVE WHAT YOU DO NOT WANT
    //[DataMember(Name = "text")]
    //public string Text { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "complete")]
    public bool Complete { get; set; }
}
```

2) Here's the code to read the data:

```
private void RefreshTodoItems()
{ 
    items = todoTable
            .OrderBy( todoItem => todoItem.Id )
            .Take(10)
            .ToCollectionView();
    ListItems.ItemsSource = items;
}
```

which is basically:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Id, Complete FROM TodoTable ORDER BY Id
```

The code example for todoTable is at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-wp8/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .net, you pretty much follow linq.
Looking at the sample app - where it has -

```
    private void RefreshTodoItems()
    {
        // This code refreshes the entries in the list view be querying the TodoItems table.
        // The query excludes completed TodoItems
        items = todoTable
            .Where(todoItem => todoItem.Complete == false)
            .ToCollectionView();
        ListItems.ItemsSource = items;
    }
```

If, for example, you did not want to return the Complete flag you could add before the call to `.ToCollectionView()`

```
.Select(item=>new {item.Id, item.Text})
```

Which would create a list of a new object of anonymous type (can be a concrete type) with the two members specified.

Comment: I add some details on my first post.